# R: 'tensorflow not found' after importing tensorflow

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to follow along with [this tutorial](http://rwanjohi.rbind.io/2018/04/05/time-series-forecasting-using-lstm-in-r/) on rbind.io. I thought instead of posting 30-40 lines of reproducible code, it's better to link to the tutorial.
I am trying to create a Time Series forecast using an LSTM neural network.

When following along with the code in the tutorial linked above, I was creating the Keras model from the RStudio Cloud, as my desktop RStudio was giving a different bug that could be resolved by working with the Cloud.

*Moving on..*

I encountered an error claiming I didn't have TensorFlow installed.

[image]

So, being the only thing to do, I installed TensorFlow.

[image]

After doing so, I encountered an error.

[image]

Now, I'm stuck. I'm not sure at all where my error is, and I request some help.

**EDIT:**
After trying what Ammar said, I still get an error.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Here's my reply to Ammar:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. First, install the tensorflow R package from GitHub as follows:

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
```

2. Then, use the install_tensorflow() function to install TensorFlow as given below. Note that on Windows you need a working installation of Anaconda.

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
```

3. You can confirm that the installation succeeded with:

```
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
## tf.Tensor(b'Hellow Tensorflow', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

As given at https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/

Comment: No, this solution isn't working. See my edit in the original question.

Comment: Could you confirm that you installed tensorflow using install.packages("tensorflow")?